# How can I configure PostFix out from our DMZ?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I'd like to configure some websites in our DMZ to be able to send emails out through PostFix to the public internet without having to pass anything to our Exchange 2010 inside our private network.

Can somebody point me in the direction of how I would go about setting this up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove configuration in relayhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just set up Postfix as the default (for most distros) "Internet site" mail server, and tell it in main.cf's mynetworks the IP's to allow for relay?

There's a couple of ways to tell it what networks to relay for if you Google for "postfix relay". Unless you tell it to use a satellite mail server it won't know anything about your Exchange server for passing messages.

Comment: This gives me somewhere to start, thanks. I'll look into setting things up as you described it. If I were to set things up this way, would I need to configure anything different on our Exchange servers inside our private network or would these continue to operate as they always have?